# Delete certain filetypes and empty folders within a folder and subfolders

Tags: command-line, find

I have a folder that is full of files and subdirectories. A lot of that is trash, but some of it I want to keep.

Therefore, I want to delete all files of a few certain types (which are the files I don't want or need) and then delete all empty directories and subdirectories.

These commands do not work at all - they do nothing:

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -type f -delete
find . -type d -empty -delete
```

I'd really appreciate any help at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `-mindepth` option to delete all the files ended with `.jpg` which was present inside subfolders,

```
find . -mindepth 1 -name "*.jpg" -type f -delete
```

To delete empty directories,

```
find . -empty -type d -delete
```

Comment: Any idea how to find and delete files WITHOUT any file extensions? There are quite a few in that directory...

Comment: using file names, you can delete files by specifying it's name.

Comment: There are a whole lot of files without extensions which are trash. I don't want to look through about 500 subdirectories to delete each one - I just want to delete them all...

Comment: I tried `find . -mindepth 1 ! -iname "*.*" -type f -delete` but it did nothing...

Comment: do you want to delete all the files which isn't has a `.` in their filenames?

Comment: I want to delete all files that have no file extensions. No . and no extension. Like "Empty" instead of "Empty.txt"

Comment: Ask it as a separate question, someone will help you.

Comment: Thanks man! The new question can be found here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/466219/find-and-delete-all-files-without-extensions-witin-a-folder-and-its-subfolders