# Find and delete all files without extensions witin a folder and its subfolders

Tags: command-line, find

I have a folder without around 500 subdirectories. There is a lot of trash to be found in it and I want to clean it up.

I have already deleted certain filetypes that I don't want, like images, with this command:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -iname "*.jpg" -type f -delete
```

However, I now want to delete all extension-less files. Files like "Shopping list" intead of "Shopping list.txt"

I have tried the following command but it did not work:

```
find . -mindepth 1 ! -iname "*.*" -type f -delete
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this:

```
find . -type f  ! -name "*.*"  -delete
```

However, note that the above will not delete files whose name ends in a `.`, for example `foo.`. To delete those as well, use this instead:

```
find . -type f  ! -name "*.?*" -delete
```

Comment: The second command was my next question. Thanks so much! I could also type `find . -type f  ! -name "*?.*" -delete` to remove files like ".trash" or whatever it was that I didn't need. Don't worry - it wasn't my Home directory, so I didn't lose any config files.

Comment: @etsnyman Better to test first the command without the `-delete` option!

Comment: @etsnyman not quite, to remove files that start with a dot, use `find . -type f  -name ".*" -delete` the one in your last comment will also delete files with no extensions. And what Radu said! Test first!

Comment: @RaduRădeanu I actually tested it first on a dummy directory with empty files...

Comment: @terdon What does the question mark means in your second command?

Comment: @AvinashRaj it means "any single character".

Comment: This perfectly answers the question. But my advice would be to first run this command without using the `-delete` flag, since you never know what all hidden files like in a `.git` are present which also does not have any extensions. So better to run the command without it which will list all the files you are going to delete. Then after confirming once, add the `-delete` flag and re-run the command.

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
find . -type f ! -name "*.*" -delete
```